# selection options in cell table are hidden by table height on open select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tom-select

I have a table that for each row, there are two cells with "select" the problem is that when opening them they are loaded inside the table and the options cannot be seen well, only if the scrollbar that is loaded when opening the "select" I can see all the options.

[image]

if a try to open it
[image]

I only see the options if I scroll the scroll bar down.
[image]

How can i fix this?

I am using Tom Select to generate the selects.

```js
var g_index =0;
var unidades_list = [
    {
        "IdUnidad": "1",
        "Nombre": "Casa conde",
        "Direccion": "Isla del coco",
        "Estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "IdUnidad": "3",
        "Nombre": "123",
        "Direccion": "999",
        "Estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "IdUnidad": "5",
        "Nombre": "casa margarita",
        "Direccion": "Isla el c",
        "Estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "IdUnidad": "6",
        "Nombre": "test",
        "Direccion": " Prueba api",
        "Estado": "1"
    },
    {
        "IdUnidad": "7",
        "Nombre": "Isla tortuga",
        "Direccion": "Colombia",
        "Estado": "1"
    }
 ]
function reload_select_unidades(IdSelect){


    let tem_unit = new TomSelect('#IdUnidad_'+IdSelect,{
        valueField: 'IdUnidad',
        labelField: 'Nombre',
        searchField: 'Nombre',
        maxItems: 1,
        options:unidades_list,
        render: {
            item: function(item, escape) {
                return `<div><span>
                            ${ escape(item.Nombre) }
                        </span></div>`;
            },
            option: function(item, escape) {
                return `<div><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                            ${ escape(item.Nombre) }
                        </a></div>`;
            }
        },
    });
 }
 jQuery(".add-new").click(function(){
    var index = jQuery("#table-data-list tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var val_index = g_index;
    var row = '<tr id="trow_'+val_index+'">' +
        '<td><input id="IdUnidad_'+val_index+'" name="IdUnidad" required></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" name="DetalleMovimiento"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" name="TC"></td>' +
        '<td>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'">$</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'" name="MontoD">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'">₡</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'" name="MontoC">'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'">$</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'" name="IVAD">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'">₡</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'" name="IVAC">'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'">$</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_D'+val_index+'" name="TotalD">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        ' <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text" id="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'">₡</span></div>'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control item-t-value" aria-describedby="simbol-addon_C'+val_index+'" name="TotalC">'+
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' + '-' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    let nele = jQuery(row);
    jQuery("#table-data-list").append(nele);
    jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    reload_select_unidades(val_index);
  g_index++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-lg">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus align-middle me-2">
                        <line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line>
                        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
                    </svg>Add New </button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table width="100%" style="min-heith:400px;" id="table-data-list" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="12.5%" >Unidad</th>
                    <th width="20%">Detalle</th>
                    <th width="8.5%">TC</th>
                    <th width="15.5%">Monto </th>
                    <th width="15.5%">IVA </th>
                    <th width="15.5%">Total </th>
                    <th style="width:50px;"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
                
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it will be very hard to assist you

Comment: It also seems like a HTML + CSS issue and unrelated to PHP.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have a lot of code for this table, what do you think would be relevant to put in the code, just the tom-select and the html table? (honest question)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more what a good question should contain. It's hard for us to know exactly what parts of your code to show when we have no idea how the page is built.

Comment: The table seems to have ```overflow:scroll``` set, meaning all elements inside the table are hidden if they exceed the boundaries. If you want to show the dropdown fully without changing table dimensions, you will have to position them outside the table.

Comment: @Lalalena Oh how stupid of me, I searched for information about what you say and found that the "table-responsible" class was the culprit. Thx!.

Comment: A cursory glance at what appears to be to the correct [documentation](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/) shows an option `dropDownParent` - set this to something outside the table wrapper, *possibly* your `cointainer-lg` but also possibly just `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just set overflow: visible for elements in creating IdUnidad.
Add class:

```
class="IdUnidad"
```

so:

```
<td><input class="IdUnidad" id="IdUnidad_'+val_index+'" name="IdUnidad" required></td>
```

css:

```
.idUnidad {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the solution I found was to remove the "table-responsive" class and it works fine now. Also thanks for your answer and I have also tried it.

Comment: Samuel's solution works.